# put where predicate in a variable

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework code first and I have code like this:

```
var foos = context.Foos.Where(f => f.Bar == "Hello World").ToList();
```

Using an SQL profiler, I see that the script run against the database contained a `WHERE` statement, as expected.

But when I put the `Where` predicate in a variable:

```
Func<Foo, bool> predicate = f => f.Bar == "Hello World");
var foos = context.Foos.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

the resulting SQL command no longer contains a `WHERE` statement.

Is there a way that this can work?

Comment: What does it include instead of a `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>`

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = f => f.Bar == "Hello World";
```

Answer (score 0):

[LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) could solve this kind issues. [It can be obtained by nuget.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)

An example about using `PredicateBuilder` of `LinqKit`.

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

### How it works

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True <Product> ();

// is just a shortcut for this:
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate = c => true;
```